# Convert the date by pd.to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the data in txt. format in this setting:

```
"PERMNO" "DATE" "TICKER" "PRC" "RET" "RETX" "vwretd" "vwretx" "ewretd" "ewretx" "sprtrn"

"1" 11850 20040102 "XOM" 40.63 -0.009024 -0.009024 -0.000786 -0.000861 0.00607 0.006048 -0.003094

"2" 11850 20040105 "XOM" 41.58 0.023382 0.023382 0.012265 0.01226 0.012936 0.012927 0.012395
```

I use read_csv to read the txt, and separate by ' '.

Right now, I want to convert the date into date format. but the original format is `20040102`, which do not match the `yy/mm/dd` format.
How can I set the `pd.to_datetime()` for this type of the date value???

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) in the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) package of Python:

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('24052010', "%d%m%Y").date()
datetime.date(2010, 5, 24)
```

in your case format of string is `%y%m%d`